# Flex build parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, package

Is it possible to define parameters to be set on installation of an .air. I want to be able to give simple information about the customer when I am installing the .air. So this information is accessible on preinitialize of the application.

Answer (score 2):

use an external xml or json in the project and tell your customer to change that xml in the install folder! This way your application can take your runtime info from there.

For your exact question, I don't think there is any. You could take the air project and wrap it in your own installer which you can customize.

Comment: How can I customize my installer. Can I use adt for that?

Comment: Here is an example http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Setup-creators/Advanced-Installer.shtml you can just google for "build installer" and you will get some other programs. Most are free. I am sure if you need to "install" an air application or you can just archive an installation and then unwrap it for the client. what does your air app do that flex or as can't?